# Docker error (exit status 127) when creating an image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a maven project that can be run by "mvn spring-boot:run" comand and which requires installed maven and PostgreSQL with DB name testdb. I used this Dockerfile :

```
# Base image
FROM openjdk:11-jdk

# Set working directory
WORKDIR E:\docketTest

# Copy the pom.xml file and download the dependencies
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

# Copy the project source
COPY src ./src

# Build the project
RUN mvn package

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 8080

# Set environment variables
ENV DB_URL jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/testdb
ENV DB_USERNAME postgres
ENV DB_PASSWORD postgres
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev

# Start the application
CMD ["java", "-jar", "target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

But when i run `docker build -t myproject E:\docketTest` i got

```
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 127): docker-untar: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1: invalid ELF header
```

Both my Dockerfile and maven project are in same directory

I expected to build my docker image using `docker build -t myproject E:\docketTest` and after that run container using
`docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=testdb -p 5432:5432 -d postgres`